# Passing arguments from a dynamic control to AddHandler in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to figure out how to pass information from one form to another using an AddHandler that I create in a dynamic control.

I have a loop something like

```
Dim I As Integer

For I = 0 To 10
    Dim gbNew As New GroupBox()
    Dim pbNew As New PictureBox()
    Dim llbNew As New Label()
    Dim tlbNew As New Label()
    Dim olbNew As New Label()
    Dim slbNew As New Label()
    Dim wlbNew As New Label()

    UserName = dt.Rows(I)("UserName").ToString()
    Status = dt.Rows(I)("LastJobType").ToString()
    JobType = dt.Rows(I)("LastJobType").ToString()
    LLocation = dt.Rows(I)("LastLocation").ToString()
    TimeIn = dt.Rows(I)("LogInTime")
    TimeOut = dt.Rows(I)("LogOutTime")
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(gbNew)

    gbNew.Controls.Add(llbNew)
    llbNew.Visible = True
    llbNew.Text = LLocation
    llbNew.Font = New Font(llbNew.Font.FontFamily, 6.5)
    llbNew.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 25)
    llbNew.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    llbNew.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
    llbNew.Size = New Size(80, 15)

    gbNew.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(270, 80)
    'gbNew.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver
    gbNew.Visible = True
    gbNew.Text = UserName & " " & I + 1

    AddHandler gbNew.Click, AddressOf ShowForm
Next
```

The eventhandler fires off a sub ShowForm:

```
Private Sub ShowForm()
    Details.Show()
End Sub
```

This in turn pops up a form, but I can't figure out how to pass a few needed bits of information from the dynamic generated control to a static control outside the loop.

I was using a static control in a form:

```
label1.text = "something"
```

And I opened the new form, and I could read that into the new form using something like
`dim info as string = form1.label.text`. But since it is dynamic, I don't have a label1.text. Instead, I have a `llbNew.Text` which seems to be something I can't call from form2 :(

How can I pass information from form1's dynamic control to form2?

Please keep this to VB.NET, not C#, as I barely understand VB.NET let alone trying to brain convert from C# which I have zero knowledge of.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a direction you could take. I hope it is clear:

```
For I = 0 To 10
    (...)
    gbNew.Text = UserName & " " & I + 1
    gbNew.Tag = dt.Rows(I) ' Any information that you need here 

    AddHandler gbNew.Click, AddressOf ShowForm  '(No changes here)
Next 

' Use the appropriate Event Handler signature @ the handler Sub
Private Sub ShowForm(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    Dim groupBoxClicked as GroupBox = TryCast(sender, GroupBox)
    If groupBoxClicked IsNot Nothing
        Dim detailsForm as New Details()
        detailsForm.ParentInformation = groupBoxClicked.Tag
        detailsForm.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub

(...)

Public Class Details ' Your Details Form
    Public Property ParentInformation as DataRow

End Class
```